# How can I find the value of this Maclaurin Series.

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, taylor-expansion

Using the four non-zero terms of Maclaurin Series how can I find the value of 
$$\int_0^1 2x \cos ^2 x dx$$

When I solved I got Maclaurin Series as $2x-2x^3+\frac{2}{3}x^5$.

But I don't know how to apply the intervals.

Can anyone show how to do this.

Comment: Please format your questions with [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) so we can read them easily.

Comment: I don't think Maclaurin series are the right approach to compute that integral.

Comment: But, I need to solve this using maclaurin series only. I have done this far and I don't know how to app those intervals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that the first 4 (**four**) terms are
$$2 x-2 x^3+\frac{2}{3} x^5 - \frac{4}{45} x^7$$
and the integral from this approximation is $\frac{3}{5}$. This is not too bad compared to the exact value
$$\cos(1) \sin(1)+\frac{1}{2}\cos(1)^2 \approx 0.600612004276\approx 0.6 = \frac{3}{5}$$

**Edit:** An antiderivative of the four term expression is
$$F(x) = x^2-\frac{1}{2}x^4+\frac{1}{9}x^6-\frac{1}{90}x^8$$
and therefore you get the integal as $F(1)-F(0) = \frac{3}{5} - 0$.

Comment: Can you please explain it elaborately about how to use upper and lower limits.

Comment: @sam: See the edit.

Comment: So, if upper limit is 2, then I just need to substitute 2 in place of x. right

Comment: Yes, that's right. But note  the approximation  is getting worse and worse if you increase the upper limit.

Answer (score 1):

The right term should be approximation.

After you found the four non-zero terms,

$$2x\cos^2(x) \approx \sum_{i=1}^7 a_i x^i$$

Integrate it term by term.

$$\int_0^12x\cos^2(x)\, dx \approx \sum_{i=1}^7 a_i \int_0^1x^i\, dx$$

Answer (score 0):

$I =\int_0^12x\cos^2(x)\,dx$

The MacLaurin  series of $f(x) = 2x\cos^2(x) $ is $2x - 2x^3 +\frac23x^5-\frac4{45}x^7 + \frac2{315}x^9........$

$I \approx \int_0^12x - 2x^3 +\frac23x^5-\frac4{45}x^7 \,dx$

$I\approx x^2-\frac12x^4 +\frac19x^6-\frac1{90}x^8\bigg]_0^1$

$I\approx 1-\frac12+\frac19-\frac1{90}$

$I \approx \frac35$

NOTE: im not sure if MacLaurin series are the best way to solve this integral ,I'd much rather use integration by parts

$I  =  (\frac{2x (\sin(2x)+x)+\cos(2x)}4)\bigg]_0^1$

$I = \frac{2.(\sin(2)+1)+\cos(2)}{4}-\frac{\cos(0)}4$

$I=0.600612$

Comment: Double-check your integration by parts.

Comment: @gammatester thank you ,i had taken 2 in degrees rather than radians. the rest was proper.